# upgrading postgresql in ec2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2

I am using postgresql `9.3.5` in ec2 instance (in a separate ebs volumn as described in http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1663)

I am planning to upgrade an instance and attach the ebs volumn to this new instance.

The new instance has postgresql `9.3.6`
Would the version difference cause the problem using the DB?

Comment: not sure if this answer is definitive, but so far so good. it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote PostgreSQL [versioning policy](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/):

> Minor releases are numbered by increasing the third part of the version number, e.g. 9.2.3 to 9.2.4. The PostgreSQL team only adds bug fixes to minor releases. All users should upgrade to the most recent minor release as soon as possible. While upgrades always have some risk, PostgreSQL minor releases fix only frequently-encountered, security, and data corruption bugs to reduce the risk of upgrading. The community considers not upgrading to be riskier than upgrading

So you're safe.

Comment: Thanks mojo. However my upgrading is a bit different (or isn't it?) I have data files in separate disk, and upgrading the binary lib/excutable on other machine.. On second thought, yes, I could have done the upgrading on the old machine (for data + for lib/excutables) and move the disk to newer machine